# Android notification remind user

Tags: android, notifications

I want to know if the user has not opened the app for a long time. How can I notify them with a push notification, without the back-end sending a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an Alarm in the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for your definition of a "long time".

When the Alarm is triggered, you can present a [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html).

Comment: Yes, i found it yesterday. and it's worked. Thanks for your share.

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer, should it be the same as your solution.